# How to make flowcharts blocks (predefined process etc) in pstricks

Tags: diagrams, pstricks, flow-charts

I want to make building blocks for program block diagrams, but I don’t understand how to make the following blocks: *I/O* block, *Predefined process*, *Internal Storage*, *Loop Limit*, *Document*, *Stored Data*, and *Database*. How do make these shapes without entering the coordinates of each figure's corners each time (most problems with internal block splitting and asymmetric edges)? I thought to do it through the pstricks table objects, but this is still too difficult for me (I am a beginner pstricks user). I have at least some idea of how to do rest blocks.

[image][image][image]

Answer (score 1):

Using an ellipse for the database maybe better ...

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{pst-node,xcolor}

\def\database{\pspicture(0,-0.2)(2,1.1)
  \psset{linecolor=black!70}
  \pscustom[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue!30]{%
    \psline(0,0)(0,1)
    \pscurve(1,1.1)(2,1)
    \psline(2,0)
    \pscurve(1,-0.1)(0,0)}%
    \pscurve(0,1)(1,0.9)(2,1)
    \pscurve(0,0.9)(1,0.8)(2,0.9)
    \pscurve(0,0.8)(1,0.7)(2,0.8)
  \endpspicture}
\def\manualInput{\pspicture(2,1.25)
  \pspolygon[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=green!30](0,0)(0,1)(2,1.25)(2,0)
  \endpspicture}

\def\dbnode(#1)#2#3{\rput(#1){\rnode{#3}{#2}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[arrowscale=2](10,10)
\dbnode(2,2){\database}{A}
\dbnode(5,5){\manualInput}{B}
\ncline{->}{A}{B}
\ncbar{->}{A}{B}
\nccurve[angleA=90,angleB=180]{->}{A}{B}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Maybe there is some standard package into pstricks packages?

Comment: Feel free to create such a package ...

Comment: as soon as I have a little time